# Am I able to run programs on a PC from a live USB flash drive?

Tags: bootable-media, gaming

I about to make a live Ubuntu USB  flash drive to play games off of, but my USB  flash drive only has about 2 gigabytes of storage. Would I be able to run games installed on my Windows 8 on my PC, from my USB flash drive?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if games that are installed on my Windows 8 PC can be run from the Ubuntu live USB flash drive..

Comment: I meant run .deb files, but I get what you mean. Thanks!